# Rails: Model validations passing in development but failing on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

In my Rails app I have a model `Link`, which has attributes `name` and `url`. Previously, `url` was not allowed to be `nil`, but I've since removed this validation. In development, I can save Links with a blank url, but in production (Heroku), the validation still fails, saying `url can not be blank`.

To illustrate, here's what happens if I run the same code at the development console and in `heroku run rails console`:

**Development:**

```
foo = Link.new(name: 'example', url: 'example.com')
foo.valid?
# true
foo = Link.new(name: 'example')
foo.valid?
# true
```

If I run this at the **heroku console** I get:

```
foo = Link.new(name: 'example', url: 'example.com')
foo.valid?
# true
foo = Link.new(name: 'example')
foo.valid?
# false
foo.errors
#<ActiveModel::Errors:0x007fbd85b95f38 @base=#<Link id: nil, name: "example", url: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>, @messages={:url=>["can't be blank"]}>
```

Why is this happening? Some points:

- `heroku restart` doesn't help
- neither has clearing and resetting the heroku db. (my app is deployed to heroku but not 'live' yet.)
- My latest changes are definitely pushed to heroku - `git diff heroku/master` returns nothing. I've even manually inspected `link.rb` on heroku and confirmed it's exactly the same as the version on my development machine.
- `url = null` is definitely allowable in the database - here's the relevant part of schema.rb:

  ```
  create_table "links", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "url"
    t.integer  "project_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
  end
  ```

Here's my **app/models/link.rb:**, as you can see there's no validation preventing url from being blank.

```
class Link < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :url

  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :project_id, presence: true

  belongs_to :project
end
```

So what the hell is going on?

Comment: Did you initially have `null: false` set on `url` in the migration file?  If so, you would need to rollback the change and then re-run the migration on heroku.  Also, if you're running unicorn, I've found that you sometimes have to push twice before all the workers restart.  Heroku restart doesn't always do the trick for me after migrations.